# Link service deployment Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have two services running on k8s and I am using an ingress to access my services. One of the service requires access to another view env but I added the cluster IP and the port of the required service but it seems to be unaccessible.

User Deployment yaml

```
...
         - name: WALLET_SERVICE_URL
              value: 'http://10.103.xxx.xx:30611'
            - name: WALLET_SERVICE_API_VERSION
              value: /api/v1
...
```

my Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/v1$uri
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: demo.localdev.me
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /user
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: accounts-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /wallet
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: wallet-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Wallet service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wallet-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: wallet-service
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3007
  type: NodePort
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `ClusterIP` for `wallet-service`. There's no reason to use `NodePort` -- the ingress controller will handle routing to the internal IP.
2. Your value for the `WALLET_SERVICE_URL` should be pointing to your service *by DNS name*, using the `port` you define for your `ClusterIP` service. i.e. `http://wallet-service:80`.
3. Unless `wallet-service` should be accessible outside of the cluster, you don't need to configure ingress for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ingress are for traffic from outside of the cluster, for internal network you can use the dns name of your service, you can read more about service dns in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)